# Интерполяционный многочлен Гаусса

Tags: python, интерполяция

```
from math import factorial

def p_cal(p, n): 
  temp = p
  for i in range(1, n):
    if(i % 2 == 1):
      temp * (p - i)
    else:
      temp * (p + i)
  return temp

x = [0.4, 0.7, 1.0, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.2]
n = len(x)
y = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)] 

for i in range(n):
    y[i][0] = x[i] ** 5

for i in range(1, n):
  for j in range(n - i):
    y[j][i] = round((y[j + 1][i - 1] - y[j][i - 1]), 4)

value = float(input('Enter х: '))
sum = y[int(n/2)][0]
p = (value - x[int(n/2)]) / (x[1] - x[0])

for i in range(1,n): 
  sum += (p_cal(p, i) * y[int((n-i)/2)][i]) / factorial(i)

print("\nValue at", value, "is", round(sum, 4))
```

Почему у меня значение по первой интерполяционной формуле Гаусса вычисляется неверно?
Функция: y = x^5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def p_cal(p, n): 
  temp = p
  for i in range(1, n):
    if(i % 2 == 1):
      temp * (p - i)
    else:
      temp * (p + i)
  return temp
```

у вас `temp` не накапливается, `p_cal` всегда возвращает `p`

надо

```
temp *= (p - i)
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо огромное. Совсем невнимательный, ошибка глупейшая